# Screen size responsiveness

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design

I am making my portfolio and checking the responsivness on phones, I noticed that the container for the landing spot shrinks into the top left of the screen. [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwnWz.png). As you can see the navbar responds normally. I cannot figure out why it does this.

Here is the component along with its CSS:

```
import React from "react";
import "./intro.css";
import headshot from "../../img/headshot1.png";


const Intro = () => {
    return (
        <section id="intro">
            <div className="introContent">
                <span className="welcome">Hello,</span>
                <span className="introText">I'm <span className="introName">Harrison Miner</span><br/>Full-Stack Web Developer</span>
                <p className="introPara">Welcome to my digital realm! I'm a passionate Full Stack Web Developer with<br/> a knack
                for crafting elegant solutions in the vast world of the web.</p>
            </div>
            <img src={headshot} alt="headshot" className="headshot"/>
        </section> 
    )
}

export default Intro;
```

```
#intro {
    height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 85rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.headshot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.introContent {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight:700;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hello {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.introName {
    color: rgb(148, 27, 12);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

.introPara {
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:840px) {
    .headshot {
        right: -10vw;
    }
    .introContent {
        font-size: 10vw;
    }
    .hello {
        font-size: 4.5vw;
    }
}
```

along with that I am going to give the main CSS style sheet for the app.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: rgb(19, 18, 18);
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I was expecting the container to dynamically respond to the screen size.

Comment: I suspect the culprit to be ... max-width: 85rem;

Comment: I just removed the 85rem but it is still shrinking